# Symbols in JSON object names

Tags: javascript, json

So I am getting some JSON data from my API, now I need to collect the values in some variables in javascript.

```
var wsize = parseInt(obj.write);
```

The wsize variable works properly as the JSON data key is just "write"

```
var rsize = parseInt(obj.read_size_hist.<=128KB);
```

but  the rsize doesn't work properly as the key is read_size_hist.<=128KB

as it has . and < and = in the name.

Can anyone help in fixing this issue?
Screenshot:
[image]

The error I am getting is :

SyntaxError: missing name after . operator
http://localhost:5000/static/main.js
Line 75

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation).

> property_name is a string. The string does not have to be a valid identifier; it can have any value, e.g. "1foo", "!bar!", or even " " (a space).

```
var rsize = parseInt(obj['read_size_hist.<=128KB']);
```